# Case statement when extracting day from date

Tags: postgresql, case, to-char

I have this code to select the day for April 23, 2012. It's supposed to return the letter 'A' but instead returns the letter 'G'.

```
SELECT
case to_char(

(select pp.datestart
from adempiere.pp_order pp
where pp.datestart = '2012-04-23'
limit 1)

, 'day')
when 'monday'
then 'A'
when 'tuesday'
then 'B'
when 'wednesday'
then 'C'
when 'thursday'
then 'D'
when 'friday'
then 'E'
when 'saturday'
then 'F'
else 'G'
end as test
```

I've selected the day itself using

```
to_char(
(select pp.datestart
from adempiere.pp_order pp
where pp.datestart = '2012-04-23'
limit 1)
, 'day') as Day
```

and it displays the day as 'monday'

Is there anything wrong with my case statement?

Answer (score 1):

I would use EXTRACT to avoid problems with language settings:

```
SELECT
    CASE EXTRACT(DOW FROM pp.datestart)
        when 1  then 'A'
        when 2  then 'B'
        when 3  then 'C'
        when 4  then 'D'
        when 5  then 'E'
        when 6  then 'F'
        else 'G'
    END as test
FROM 
    adempiere.pp_order pp
WHERE 
    pp.datestart = '2012-04-23'
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_char(date, 'day')` returns the string blank-padded to 9 chars: [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).